# Creating proxy for HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, stream

I have a web service that needs to take the request from the client, forward it on to a back-end service after tweaking the URL, then send the response back to the client.

However, when I run it and point a browser at my service, the browser sits there waiting for a response and eventually times out.

If I step through the service in the debugger, it executes everything fine and returns from the ProcessRequest method successfully.

If I inspect the traffic in Fiddler, I can see that my service sends the correct response headers back, but there seems to be no body to the response.

My code is:

```
public class ForwardRequest : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri url = ConstructURL(context.Request.Url);

            // Create the request object that we'll use to forward the request 
            HttpWebRequest forwardRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            CopyRequestHeaders(context.Request, forwardRequest);

            // Get the response back 
            HttpWebResponse response = forwardRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            // Copy the response back to the client
            CopyResponseHeaders(response, context.Response);
            using (Stream answer = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                answer.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                context.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            // make sure the response is closed properly.
            try { context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); }
            catch { };
        }
    }

    // Copy headers (and other info) from one response object to another
    private void CopyResponseHeaders(HttpWebResponse source, HttpResponse destination)
    {
        foreach (var headerKey in source.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            destination.Headers[headerKey] = source.Headers[headerKey];
        }
        destination.ContentType = source.ContentType;
    }

    // Copy headers (and other info) from one request object to another
    // This method copied from a post on Stackoverflow.com
    private void CopyRequestHeaders(HttpRequest source, HttpWebRequest destination)
    {
        destination.Method = source.HttpMethod;

        // Copy the headers we're able to
        foreach (var headerKey in source.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            switch (headerKey)
            {
                case "Connection":
                case "Content-Length":
                case "Date":
                case "Expect":
                case "Host":
                case "If-Modified-Since":
                case "Range":
                case "Transfer-Encoding":
                case "Proxy-Connection":
                    // Let IIS handle these
                    break;

                case "Accept":
                case "Content-Type":
                case "Referer":
                case "User-Agent":
                    // Restricted - copied below
                    break;

                default:
                    destination.Headers[headerKey] = source.Headers[headerKey];
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Copy restricted headers
        if (source.AcceptTypes.Any())
        {
            destination.Accept = string.Join(",", source.AcceptTypes);
        }
        destination.ContentType = source.ContentType;
        if (source.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            destination.Referer = source.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        destination.UserAgent = source.UserAgent;

        // Copy content (if content body is allowed)
        if (source.HttpMethod != "GET" && source.HttpMethod != "HEAD" && source.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var destinationStream = destination.GetRequestStream();
            source.InputStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
            destinationStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I perhaps copying the initial response to the context.Response object incorrectly? Why does the request to my service never seem to complete?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with requests timing out. Last time I had this problem it was related to not properly closing connections, and there where no available sockets left so the entire application just hung.

Below is a code snippet I've used to send http post requests.

```
public void Run() {
    string url = "http://example.com/api";
    string contentType = "application/xml";
    string postData = "<this><is><my>xml</my></is></this>";

    string responseBody = PostRequest(url, contentType, postData);
}


public string PostRequest(string url, string contentType, string postData) 
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;

        Log.Debug("HTTP request: [" + request.Method + "] " + url);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        Log.Debug("HTTP response: " + response.StatusCode + " - " + response.StatusDescription);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        return responseBody;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error("Exception while running HTTP request.", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```